# is possible put a $Variable inside file.txt

Tags: bash, variables

i have a little bashscript:

```
mail_body_file="mailbody.txt"


for fullname in *.zip; do
    filename="${fullname%.*}"
mutt -a $fullname -s "Attachment $fullname" xxx@xxx.com < $mail_body_file
```

I have two question;

- -is possible put the **$filename** inside mailbody.txt ?
- -is possible put it in a specific line of mailbody.txt ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the content of variable `$filename` into `mailbody.txt`, for example at line 5, you could do this:

```
sed '5i\'$filename mailbody.txt > output.txt
mv output.txt mailbody.txt
```

Comment: I have a prolbem, I can not delete the file generate from script mailbody.txt with rm-rf mailbody.txt

Comment: probably because of permission problem. Try the following command: sudo chown yourusername filename

Then you should get permission to delete it.